# Google Contacts API: Filter by query AND group?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-contacts-api

I have a working integration with the Google Contacts API, but one step isn't returning the results I had expected.

When I get a list of contacts in a group (e.g. "My Contacts") it returns the expected number of contacts:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?
  group=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{userEmail}/base/6
  &alt=json&v=3.0
```

And when I pass a query parameter instead of a group parameter, it returns all contacts who match that query.

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?
  q=Alan&alt=json&v=3.0
```

BUT, when I combine `q=term` and `group=[...]` I expect to get only contacts who match the query and are in My Contacts. Instead, I get both the query results AND My Contacts.

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?
  q=Alan&group=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{userEmail}/base/6
  &v=3.0&alt=json
```

Does anyone know how to make this query behave like an AND search instead of OR?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate question, please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824862/google-contact-api-v3-q-parameter-is-ignored-if-search-in-a-contact-group?rq=1.

Comment: The outcome I see is different, but yes, they definitely seem related. What should I do with this question?

Comment: I'm trying to use the group filter, but it's not working. Could you explain it to me ?
My request : https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?access_token=' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token + '&group=https://google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default' + '&alt=json&max-results=9999999&v=3.0