# Google Contacts API - how to filter only email contacts

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-contacts-api

This is the java-script sample code I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function auth() {
    var config = {
      'client_id': 'your client ID HERE',
      'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
      fetch(gapi.auth.getToken());  

    });
  }

  function fetch(token) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + token.access_token + "&alt=json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success:function(data) {
                          // display all your data in console
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```

But this is importing both email contacts and phone contacts. Is there any option to filter in javascript to get **ONLY the email contacts** ?

Currently I am filtering after importing both contacts from Google .

Any help will be appreciable.

Please Note:  This is not a duplicate question. Similar questions are available in stackoverflow, but are not exactly suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I googled and looked around the community for quite some time but didn't find anything that serves as a direct filter that you can add in your request only to filter out email contacts. What I suggest you could do though is to *group* your email contacts, then [retrieve the contact group](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_single_contact_group) by using the `group` parameter.

Don't know if this might be useful for you, but gonna go on ahead and include it here, be mindful about using both the `query` and `group` parameters together, found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24824862/6124253) that says that they don't work together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use q=@ in your query.
It means it makes a textual search of the letter "@" in every field, and as such
returns (almost) only results with email addresses.